# How can you source in a file of .markdown -format?

Tags: bash, markdown

I have a file which needs many tables in html.
I have the tables in separate files.

I run in a `file.markdown` unsuccessfully

```
source ./table.html
```

**How can you source in a file of .markdown -format?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), there isn't a tool within markdown to do what you want.

Usually if you want to do this, you can create a small script to put the tables into the markdown where you want with a replacement of a token in the markdown text.  You can do this in for example bash script by this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat testfile | (
  while read i; do
    if [ "$i" == "##TABLESAREHERE##" ]; then
       cat table_file
    else
       echo $i
    fi
  done
)
```

when you run your script, it will then generate the final markdown which will be used.

Comment: Your script seems to put the table inside the file in .markdown -format.

Comment: .markdown accepts inline HTML.  What is the problem?